# How to create a pointer to a multi dimensional array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Before anyone closes this question because there's another related one, hear me out. I've already looked at the other question and I didn't get it. I would like to create a pointer to a multi dimensional array but I don't know how. I thought I was supposed to do it like this:

```
int test_arr[2][4];
int *ptr_array = test_arr;
```

But when I do that, I get a warning saying:

```
incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'int [2][4]'
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me please?

Comment: try `int (*ptr_array)[4] = test_arr;`

Comment: You haven't actually told us what you're trying to accomplish. What's the big picture? What are you intending to do with that pointer?

Comment: @user3386109 I'm just practicing. I'm not going to use it for a project

Answer (score 2):

In order to do pointer arithmetic the pointer has to know the size of what it is pointing to.

`int test_arr[2][4];` is equivalent to 2 elements of type `int[4]`. So whenever you add 1 to the pointer, it will jump the size of 4 integers. If you had `int*` it would increment the size of a single integer only.

Like said in the comments, what you want is: `int (*ptr_array)[4] = test_arr;`

I know, the syntax is a little weird, but that's how you do it.

Comment: Ok let's see If i can break it down. Obviously, int is the data type. test_arr is a pointer to test_arr[0] and it's being assigned to (*ptr_array)[4]. But why do you need the parentheses around the indirection operator and the pointer name?

Comment: @MatthewSchell Because `[]` has higher precedence than `*`. So `int *ptr_array[4]` **is an array** that contains 4 pointers, but `int (*ptr_array)[4]` **is a pointer** that points to an array of 4 `int`.

Comment: Oh right. Thanks for clarifying. and the [4] is needed for what again? because it's the size of an integer right?

Comment: No, the 4 is because you defined an array of size 4. It could be any other number. When you do `pt_array + 10` it will jump the space equivalent to 40 integers. If you had declared `(*ptr_array)[10]` and did the same `pt_array + 10` it would jump 100 integers. each increment in the pointer would jump 10 integers.

Comment: You have a pointer to `int array of size 4`. You shouldn't use it to point to arrays of different sizes (you can do it, C will allow but the pointer arithmetic would be painful).

Comment: But what do you need the size for? I thought a pointer was just a numerical address. why can't I just do `int *ptr_array = test_arr`

Comment: Because that would be a pointer to int, not int[4]. You probably could do that with a cast. But If you wouldnt be able to access elements as If they were in a matrix. Ptr[0] would be test[0][0] and ptr[5] would be test[1][0].

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the basics.
*[Below in post, read `1D` as `1` dimension and `2D` as `2` dimension]*

First, lets take an example of pointer to `1D` array:

Take an `int` type and a pointer pointing to it:

```
int x = 1;
int *px = &x;
```

The type of x is `int` and the type of `&x` is `int *` and type of `px` is `int *` i.e. it can hold the address of an `int` type variable. Hence the assignment is valid.

Take a `1D` `int` array and a pointer pointing to it:

```
int arr[2] = {1,2};
int *parr = arr;
```

Note that the type of `px` and `parr` is same i.e. `int *` and assigning `arr` to `parr` is completely valid although the `arr` is a `1D` array.
This is because of the fact that, in C, **an *array of type* converted to *pointer of type*  that points to the initial element of the array object** but there are few exceptions to this rule and one of them is when used unary `&` operator.
The type of `arr` is `int [2]` but in the above statment (`parr` declare and initialisation statement) it is converted to pointer pointing to initial element of array which is an integer i.e. `arr` is converted to `int *` type in the `int *parr = arr;` statement. Hence, it is valid to assign `arr` to `parr` or to any variable of type `int *`.

As, I have mentioned that there are few exceptions to the rule (*array of type* converted to *pointer of type*....) and one of the exception is when used unary `&` operator. So type of `&arr` will be `int (*)[2]`. That means you can assign `&arr` to any variable of type `int (*)[2]`.

```
int (*parr2)[2] = &arr;
```

i.e. `parr2` is a pointer to an array of `2` integer.

The difference between this

```
int *parr = arr;
```

and

```
int (*parr2)[2] = &arr;
```

is that `parr` can hold address of any `int` pointer but `parr2` can hold the address of any array of `2` integers. **Both are pointing to same address but their *types* are different**.

If you understood the above mentioned things completely then read below otherwise read the above part again.

Now lets come to `2D` array.

Take a `2D` array and a pointer pointing to it:

```
int arr[2][2];
int (*ptr)[2] = arr;
```

In the above `ptr` declare and initialisation statement, the type of `arr` is `int (*)[2]`. *Why??*
Recall the rule mentioned above - *array of type converted to pointer of type that points to the initial element of the array object*.
`arr` is array of `2` `1D` arrays of size `2` (`2` `int` elements). So, it's first element is array of `2` `int` and, by rule, it will be converted to pointer to the initial element i.e. pointer to
`1D` array of `2` `int` which is `int (*)[2]`.
Hence, you can assign `arr` to a pointer variable of type `int (*)[2]`.

The type of `&arr` is `int (*)[2][2]`, so this is also perfectly fine:

```
int (*ptr2)[2][2] = &arr;
```

So, **there are two ways you can have pointer to `2D` `arr` but remember that the *types* of `ptr` and `ptr2` is different**. This matters, for e.g., if you add `1` to pointer `ptr` it will be incremented by size of `int [2]` but if you add `1` to `ptr2` it will be incremented by size of `int [2][2]`.

**How to access the array members using pointer:**

In case of `1D` array:

```
int arr[2] = {1,2};
int *parr = arr;
int (*parr2)[2] = &arr;

// access arr members via parr pointer
printf ("%d\n", parr[0]);  // this will give value of first member of array arr

// access arr members via parr2 pointer
printf ("%d\n", (*parr2)[0]);  // this will give value of first member of array arr
```

Similarly, in case of `2D` array:

```
int test_arr[2][4];
int (*ptr_array)[4] = test_arr;
int (*ptr_array2)[2][4] = &test_arr;

// access test_arr members via ptr_array pointer
printf ("%d\n", ptr_array[0][0]); // this will give value of first member of array test_arr

// access test_arr members via ptr_array2 pointer
printf ("%d\n", (*ptr_array2)[0][0]); // this will give value of first member of array test_arr
```

Based on above explanation, try yourself creating multidimensional array (> `2D` array) pointers and play with them.

Hope, above explanation resolves your all confusions related to pointer to a `2D` array and you understood now why compiler is giving *incompatible pointer types ....* warning on statement `int *ptr_array = test_arr;`. It's all about *type* compatibility during initialisation/assignment.